# Assembly 8086 question - having trouble with deleting the bmp picture from the screen

Tags: assembly, x86-16, vga

I printed a `bmp` image on my screen and I have no idea how to make that picture disappear after clicking something. I do know the "*wait for key press*" stuff but I don't know how to make the picture disappear.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You just have to draw new pixels on top of the old ones.

Comment: Or set the graphic videomode again.

Comment: ty guys it worked